# mySQL - User's total points count in different ranges with Dynamic Ranges

Tags: mysql, fetch

When i am trying to execute following query it gives me proper result but i want to show range dynamically

```
 SELECT
 CASE
 WHEN points <= 25 THEN '0-25'
 WHEN points BETWEEN 25 AND 50 THEN '25-50'
 WHEN points BETWEEN 50 AND 75 THEN '50-75'
 WHEN points BETWEEN 75 AND 100 THEN '75-100'
 ELSE '> 100'
 END AS `Range`
 ,COUNT(*) AS `Count`
 ,CASE
 WHEN points <= 25 THEN 1
 WHEN points BETWEEN 25 AND 50 THEN 2
 WHEN points BETWEEN 50 AND 75 THEN 3
 WHEN points BETWEEN 75 AND 100 THEN 4
 ELSE 5
 END AS `Sort`
 FROM (
 SELECT user_id, SUM(points) as points
 FROM tbl
 GROUP BY user_id
 ) AS summary
 GROUP BY `Range`, `Sort`
```

**Output**

```
+--------+-------+
| Range  | Count |
+--------+-------+
| 0-20   | 01    |
| 25-50  | 02    |
| 50-75  | 01    |
| 75-100 | 04    |
| > 100  | 00    |
+--------+-------+
```

I am getting 100 value from following value from another table

SELECT MIN(points) FROM tbl1 where 1 LIMIT 0,1

If min value will be 100 then output will be:

**Output**

```
+--------+-------+
| Range  | Count |
+--------+-------+
| 0-20   | 01    |
| 25-50  | 02    |
| 50-75  | 01    |
| 75-100 | 04    |
| > 100  | 00    |
+--------+-------+
```

If min value will be 500 then output will be:

**Output**

```
+---------+-------+
| Range   | Count |
+---------+-------+
| 0-100   | 01    |
| 100-200 | 02    |
| 300-400 | 01    |
| 400-500 | 04    |
| > 500   | 00    |
+---------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN points <= range1 THEN CONCAT('0-', range1)
            WHEN points <= range2 THEN CONCAT(range1, '-', range2)
            WHEN points <= range3 THEN CONCAT(range2, '-', range3)
            WHEN points <= range4 THEN CONCAT(range3, '-', range4)
            ELSE CONCAT('> ', range4)
       END AS `Range`
       ,COUNT(*) AS `Count`
       ,LEAST(5, GREATEST(1, CEIL(points/range1))) AS Sort
FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(points) as points
      FROM tbl
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) AS summary
JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(MIN(points)*.25) range1, FLOOR(MIN(points)*.50) range2, FLOOR(MIN(points)*.75) range3, MIN(points) range4 FROM tbl1) x
GROUP BY `Range`, `Sort`
```

Notice that you don't need to use `BETWEEN` in the `WHEN` clauses. The clauses are tested in order, so if it gets past `points <= 25`, it must be greater than `25` and it's not necessary to test that explicitly in the next clause.

Comment: When my min value is 500 it still showing ranges like 0-25,25-50 it should be 0-100,100-200

Comment: I just fixed an error in my multipliers, but that wouldn't explain your results. There's no way you could be getting ranges like that from my code. Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I'm confused by your examples. When min is 100 you go up by 1/4 of that, but when min is 500 you go up by 1/5. But you're missing a range, 200-300.

Comment: sorry for mistake it should include range 200-300

Comment: So should the last one be `>400`? I don't understand your general rule for going from the `min(points)` to the ranges.

Comment: If min count is 100
-------------------

100 / 4

> 100

75-100

50-75

25-50

0-25


If min count is 500
-------------------

500 / 4

> 500

375-500

250-375

125-250

0-125

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39973/discussion-between-andy-martin-and-barmar)

Comment: I added FLOOR functions.